# How do I create a stop for the Application.OnTime event in my code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code here that works perfectly except for when I try to close the Excel Sheet. I have tried to program the timer to stop when i close the Workbook but it does not seem to be working. Whenever I close the workbook it automatically re-opens. Any help with tweaking my code would be gratly appreciated. Here it is:

Code in Module 1:

```
    Dim RT1 As Date
    Dim Lunch As Date
    Dim ApT As Date
    Dim RT3 As Date
    Dim NextTick As Date

    Public Sub UpdateTime()
    ' Places a bug fix for stopping the clock when closing the workbook
    Debug.Print "UpdateTime" & Format(RunWhen, "00:00:00")
    ' Updates cell D8 with the Current time
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D8") = Now()
    ' Set up next event 1 second from now
    NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime NextTick, "UpdateTime"
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopClock()
    ' Cancels the OnTime event
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime NextTick, "UpdateTime", , False
    End Sub
```

Code in Module 2:

```
    Sub PhoneHours()
    'Time left at the beginning of the day
    If Range("B12") < Range("A3") Then Range("E12").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[3]C[-3]-R[0]C[-3])-        (2*R[0]C[1])"
    'Time left after the first Research Time Has passed
    If Range("B12") >= Range("A3") Then Range("E12").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[3]C[-3]-R[0]C[-3])-        (1.75*R[0]C[1])"
    'Time left after Lunch and Second Research Time
    If Range("B12") >= Range("B3") Then Range("E12").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[3]C[-3]-R[0]C[-3])-        (0.5*R[0]C[1])"
    'Time left afetr Apple Time
    If Range("B12") >= Range("D3") Then Range("E12").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[3]C[-3]-R[0]C[-3])-        (0.25*R[0]C[1])"
    'Time left after Final Research Time
    If Range("B12") >= Range("E3") Then Range("E12").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[3]C[-3]-R[0]C[-3])"

    NextCheck = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime NextCheck, "PhoneHours"

    End Sub

    Sub StopCheck()
    ' Cancels the OnTime event
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime NextCheck, "PhoneHours", , False
    End Sub
```

Code in ThisWorkbook:

```
    Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Call StopClock
    Call StopCheck
    End Sub

    Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call UpdateTime
    Call PhoneHours
    End Sub

    Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call UpdateTime
    Call PhoneHours
    End Sub

    Sub Workbook_Close()
    Call StopClock
    Call StopCheck
    End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: NextCheck, or NextTick ? Assume you only meant to use one of those...

Answer (score 0):

When I tried do something similar I found that the main problem was that OnTime calls were being raised far more frequently than I expected - if you put a debug.print in your PhoneHours sub then you'll see that this is the case here. Your StopCheck routine is only cancelling the latest call, but all earlier ones are still active (and are causing the book to be reopened after closing).

You may want to create some breakpoints/debugs to find out exactly where and why each one is being called in order to make your sheet run more efficiently, but in any case I found that the most reliable way of cancelling all future ontime calls was a bit of a scattergun approach as follows:

```
Sub StopCheck()
    ' Cancels the OnTime event
    Debug.Print "Cancelled Phonehours"
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Cancels all OnTime events scheduled in the next 15 seconds
    For i = 0 To 15
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & i), "PhoneHours", , False
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

and

```
Public Sub StopClock()
    ' Cancels the OnTime event
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print "Cancelled UpdateTime"
    ' Cancels all OnTime events scheduled in the next 3 seconds
    For i = 0 To 3
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & i), "UpdateTime", , False
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This should leave no remaining future OnTimes scheduled and you should be able to close your sheet successfully.

(Incidentally, should your Worksheet_Deactivate be a Workbook_Deactivate?)